# Change logging level of a single Gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Does Gradle allow to change logging level during execution of a single chosen task, without affecting the other ones? One of the tasks in my script has some pretty important output, but it's shown only when run with at least info (`-i`) level - which floods the output with a lot of other data that I don't need. Ideally, I'd like to be able to set the task logging level through the `build.gradle` configuration.

Comment: [It seems that it cannot be done yet.](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1010)

Comment: I have the same except issue with the built-in `uploadArchives` task: enabling INFO level logging just for this one task would flood the build output with a lot of unnecessary details

Comment: I've turned your comment into its own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642701/1108305

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but Gradle issue [#1010](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1010) (opened ten years ago as [GRADLE-2658](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2658) before being migrated from Jira to GitHub) requests this functionality.

> ## Ability to set log level for specific task
>
> As a user, I would like to be able to debug just one specific task. Something like:
>
> ```
> task myTask {
>   logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
>
>   doLast {
>     logger.info("Output on INFO level")
>   }  
> }
> ```
>
> #### Expected Behavior
>
> Given the build file above, I'd like "Output on INFO level" to be printed if I run `gradle myTask`
>
> #### Current Behavior
>
> Currently, "Output on INFO level" is not logged.